# Proof of Set Interior Equality

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $M \subset X$. Show that:
$$\overset{\circ}{M} = \bigcup_{\substack{B\subset M \\ B \text{ open}}} B$$

I tried to prove it by using the definition:
$$\overset{\circ}{M} = M \setminus \partial M \iff m \in M \land x \notin \partial M \iff x \in M \land \exists \epsilon > 0: B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap M^{C} = \emptyset$$
Since we have the union of all subsets contained in $M$, $x$ is in at least one $B$, and by the second statement after "and", we can be sure it is open.

I have encountered difficulty in proving the statement, and my attempted proof does not appear to be elegant or correct. Could someone kindly offer assistance? Your support would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting. I have always known the interior of $M$ to be *defined* as the largest open set contained within $M$. But fine, let's assume the interior $\text{Int} M$ is defined as the set-theoretic difference $M - \text{Bd} M$, where $\text{Bd} M$, the *boundary* of $M$ (or $\partial M$), is the collection of points $x$ such that every neighborhood* $U$ of $x$ intersects both $M$ and $X - M$ (where $X$ is your entire space). We will show that

$$M - \text{Bd} M = \bigcup_{B \subseteq M \\ B \text{ open}} B$$

($\subseteq$) Let $x \in M - \text{Bd} M$. To show that $x \in \bigcup_{B \subseteq M \\ B \text{ open}} B$, we just have to show that there is an open set $B_x$, contained in $M$, with $x \in B_x$. Since $x \notin \text{Bd} M$, there is a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ that does not intersect either $M$ or $X - M$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $U_x$ does not intersect $M$. Then $U_x \subseteq X - M$. But $x \in M \implies x \notin X - M \implies x \notin U_x$, contradicting the hypothesis that $U_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. This shows that $U_x$ does not intersect $X - M$; i.e., $U_x \subseteq M$, as desired.

($\supseteq$) Trivial. Let $x \in \bigcup_{B \subseteq M \\ B \text{ open}} B$; then there is an open set $B$ containing $x$ with $B \subseteq M$. This firstly shows that $x \in M$. It also shows that $B$ does not intersect $X - M$, which means $x \notin \text{Bd} M$, by definition. So, $x \in M - \text{Bd} M$, as desired.

---

*When I say "neighborhood" of $x$, I mean an *open set* containing $x$. Since it looks like you are working in a metric space, you can take this to be a basis element $B_d (x, \varepsilon)$, with $\varepsilon > 0$, but this concept applies generally to topological spaces.